# htaccess, one line does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this htaccess file. Everything is working fine except that first RewriteRule. 
When I open localhost/music/test/ I get a 404 not found error.
When I open localhost/music/ or localhost/music/a/b/etc/ it works like it should.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1&sid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1&sid=$2&tid=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1&sid=$2&tid=$3&fid=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1&sid=$2&tid=$3&fid=$4&fiid=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1&sid=$2&tid=$3&fid=$4&fiid=$5&siid=$6 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1&sid=$2&tid=$3&fid=$4&fiid=$5&siid=$6&seid=$7 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1&sid=$2&tid=$3&fid=$4&fiid=$5&siid=$6&seid=$7&eiid=$8 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Could the apache conf or the virtualhost break the htacces file for one line?

**apache conf is the default conf (apt-get apache2)**

**virtualhost file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin wouter1994_67@hotmail.com
    ServerName sites
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites
    <Directory /var/www/sites>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Note: the music dir is inside the sites dir

Comment: Any chance of index.php throwing the 404 for that particular combination of parameters?

Comment: Nope, the index.php is `$URL[1] = $_GET['id'];
 $URL[2] = $_GET['sid'];
 $URL[3] = $_GET['tid'];
 $URL[4] = $_GET['fid'];
 $URL[5] = $_GET['fiid'];
 $URL[6] = $_GET['siid'];
 $URL[7] = $_GET['seid'];
 $URL[8] = $_GET['eiid'];
 print_r($URL);die;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond` directives only affect the first immediate `RewriteRule`, so the 3 conditions you have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
```

Are only applied to the first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /music/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And all the other rules aren't bound by those 3 conditions. The reason why the first rule probably never gets applied is because you have the condition: `%{REQUEST_URI} !/$` which says *if the URI does **not** end with a slash*. But the rule itself requires that the URI ends with a slash (`^([^/]*)/$`). I'm going to assume that your conditions are missing a `^` in front of them and that you meant:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

As in, *does **not** start with a .* and *is not a /*. You'll also want to duplicate those conditions for each of the RewriteRule entries that you have if you want them to also be applied to the other rules.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with the htacess file but you could just make it redirect all traffic going to music/test to music/a/b/ect

Comment: I would like to have it fixed without a redirect like that, it should work and I hate it to not be able to find the fix haha